# Pthread with define argument

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

This is my first time posting my own question, so sorry if I break etiquette or something in some way. Most of the software in this program I'm working on wasn't coded by me. I'm wanting to create a thread using one of their functions.The function I want to implement in the thread looks like this. If possible I would like to be able to continue using pthreads:

```
void * bpsk_continuous(
uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::sptr usrp,
const std::string &cpu_format,
const std::string &wire_format,
const std::string &file,
size_t samps_per_buff,
unsigned long long num_requested_samples,
double time_requested = 0.0,
bool bw_summary = false,
bool stats = false,
bool null = false,
bool enable_size_map = false,
bool continue_on_bad_packet = false
){//operations of function}
```

Later they use syntax very unfamiliar to me that I'm assuming defines the arguments in some way. My first question would be what is the following code doing.

```
#define bpsk_continuous_args(format) \
(usrp, format, wirefmt, file, spb, total_num_samps, total_time, bw_summary, stats, null, enable_size_map, continue_on_bad_packet)
//if (type == "float") recv_to_file<std::complex<float> >recv_to_file_args("fc32");
```

My second question would be how can I create a thread that runs the bpsk_continuous argument given the syntax above. I tried the following but no dice:

```
pthread_t t1;
pthread_create(&t1, NULL, bpsk_continuous,bpsk_continuous_args("fc32"));
```

Comment: `std::string` looks more like `C++` than `C`.  Suggest changing tag.

Comment: Hard to say what that macro is used for without seeing it in action. At first glance it looks like a macro that is used for short-handing invocations to the continuous function who's prototype you listed at the top of your question (and assumes there are many global or automatic vars of some very specific names). Also, you can't use that function as a direct pthread-function, which requires **one** parameter (a `void*`). You'll have to write a forwarder and invoke that, then your desired function from there. Personally, I'd consider `std::thread` if it is available on your platform.

Comment: Don't use pthread_create but std::thread. Then, using a std::function, you can bind() parameters, and in that place you can use this macro to generate the parameters.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt if possible I'd like to continue using pthreads

Comment: Just do a quick cut/paste job to see the effects of the macro.

Answer (score 4):

You should create auxiliary struct, and the start routine, lets say:

```
struct bpsh_args {
    uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::sptr usrp;
    std::string cpu_format;
    std::string wire_format;
    std::string file;
    size_t samps_per_buff;
    unsigned long long num_requested_samples;
    double time_requested;
    bool bw_summary;
    bool stats;
    bool null;
    bool enable_size_map;
    bool continue_on_bad_packet;
};
```

In the start routine you should cast it's only argument back to bpsh_args:

```
void* start_routine(void* _args) {
    bpsh_args* args = static_cast<bpsh_args*>(_args);
    bpsk_continuous(args->usrp, args->cpu_format, ...);
}
```

Then fill bpsh_args with appropriate data and then pass the pointer to it as last argument of pthread_create, and start_routine as one before last.

```
bpsh_args _bpsh_args;
_bpsh_args.usrp = ....;
_bpsh_args.cpu_format = "fc32";
...
pthread_create(&t1, NULL, start_routine, &_bpsh_args);
```

Consult man or http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html for details.

Be aware of the fact that after a new thread is started the struct with arguments is shared between two threads and the _args will be invalid if the variable _bpsh_args goes out of scope. Maybe you should better allocate it on heap, or add some synchronisation primitives to ensure that _bpsh_args is alive as long as you use it in descendant thread.

Comment: Apart from the use of reinterpret_cast where a static_cast would be appropriate, this is a sane approach.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, what the #define does, it is a so-called macro. Macros just perform text replacement. Just do a little research and you will find out more about them, in particular that they are generally considered an evil feature of C++.

Then, if you need to rule out using a portable approach like std::thread (or even Boost's variant thereof), try this approach:

```
void* thread_function(void* arg)
{
    assert(arg);
    std::string const& format = *static_cast<std::string*>(arg);
    return bpsk_continuous bpsk_continuous_args(format);
}

somewhere()
{
    std::string format = ...;
    pthread_create(.., &thread_function, &format, ..);
}
```

Note that this library is from what I can tell shoddy C++. The use of lower-case macros. Using them to work around its own overly long parameter lists. The seeming lack of understanding for namespaces. These all seems like a poor design choices to me and I wouldn't be surprised to find more of them.